# How to print out contents of a text file

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a file and i want to print ou the contents of it but i cant get my functions working can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
  MenuText text;
  string test = "Champion";
  ofstream output("File.txt");
  text.save(output);
  fstream output ("File.txt");
  text.load("File.txt");//This is an error.
  text.print();


MenuText::MenuText()
{
    mText = "Default";

}
MenuText :: MenuText(string text)
{
mText = text;
}
void MenuText::print()
{
cout<< "Story= " << mText<< endl;
cout<< endl;
}
void MenuText::save(ofstream& outFile)
{
outFile<<   "/         .   \  \____    \\   \\    _ -. "
            //"/    /__        -    \/\_______\\__\\__\ \"
            "__\  /\   __   \     .      \/_______//__//"
            "__/\/__/ \  \   \_\  \       -   ________  "
            "___    ___  ______  \  \_____/     -  /\    "
            "__    \\   -.\    \\   ___\ \/_____/    ."
            "\  \  \__\   \\   \-.      \\   __\_        "
            "-   \ _\_______\\__\  `\___\\_____\           "
            ".     \/_______//__/    /___//_____/ "<< mText<< endl;
cout<< endl;
outFile<< endl;
}
void MenuText::load(ifstream& inFile)
{
string garbage;
inFile>> garbage >> mText;
}
The errors are:
Error   1   error C2371: 'output' : redefinition; different basic types c:\users\conor\documents\college\c++ programming\marooned\marooned\mainapp.cpp  15  1   Marooned
Error   2   error C2664: 'MenuText::load' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [9]' to 'std::ifstream &'   c:\users\conor\documents\college\c++ programming\marooned\marooned\mainapp.cpp  16  1   Marooned
```

Comment: Could you please show us the error when re-load the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MenuText::load()` takes an `ifstream&` as its only argument, not a `const char*`. Create an instance of an [`ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) and pass it to `MenuText::load()`:

```
std::ifstream input("File.txt");
if (input.is_open())
{
    text.load(input);
}
```

Also, [`close()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/close) the `output` stream to ensure all data written is flushed before creating the `ifstream`.

The `MenuText::load()` will not read the entire content of the file into memory. It will store the second string encountered in the file to `mText` as `operator>>` will stop reading at the first whitespace character.

Comment: That worked :).  i need some work on my print method because its not printing out the contents.

Comment: Any idea how to fix the print method ?

Comment: @Pendo826, the `print()` method is correct it is the `load()` method that is not.

Comment: What would i need to do to fix this >?